# How to export process template and import into another organization using azure devops api?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I want to export process template from one organization and import into another organization.

I am referring the documentation [export/import process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/import-process-template?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

I want to achieve few things like

1. If template not exist then it should create into another organaization
2. If template exist then

   - it should add all new workitemtype and its setting
   - if workitem type exist then it should override the existing setting and new setting should be added for existing workitem type

How can I achieve mention points?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export/import Inherited processes, this is not supported.

Please refer the same issue ticket [How to export/import process template in Azure DevOps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-exportimport-process-template-in-azure-devo/841495).

And it mentioned in this [Upload or download a process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019) ,

> Important :
> Uploading and downloading Inherited processes isn't supported.

Import and export a Hosted XML process feature is only available for organizations that have been migrated to Azure DevOps Services from Azure DevOps Server. Please refer [Import and export a Hosted XML process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/import-process/import-process?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks @Miao, i refered this link. Can I manually call ADO api to get the process template and related entities as mentioned in ADO api doc or Client library available and then manually call api to add/edit/delete template and workitemtype and associated entities in target place?

Comment: For the Inherited processes, I only found these Processes APIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0.

Comment: May I know if your process is Inherited processes or Hosted XML process?